# Run .exe from PHP in IIS Server?

Tags: c#, php, html, iis

I am trying to run an .exe of an application, which I have done in C #, from PHP on an IIS server and it doesn't work. I tried with `exec`, with `shell_exec` and with `system`.

I copy my current script:

Comment: It have executed, but the result is not you wanted.

Comment: `-532462766` is the result code of your execution. If you want the text output of the execution, please use [shell_exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) instead of `system()`.

Comment: Error -532462766, or 0xE0434352... sounds like the `IIS_IUSRS` account (or whatever your application's default account is) doesn't have read-execute permissions on the `PruebaDBF.exe` file or one of its parent folders.

Comment: If you're GUI-oriented you can right-click on the `PruebaDBF.exe` file from Windows Explorer and go to Properties... > Security tab. Whatever your application's default user account is should be listed there with Read permissions (or Read-Execute when looking in Advanced mode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I monitor system() run in IIS. I also notice that IIS is running php application with IIS application pool identity. Have you ever tried to grant application pool identity(IIS Apppool\apppool name) read permission to access the application PrueDBF.ex？

I think MS process monitor would help you check read/write status. It would probably help you find the root cause.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon